# firefox extension adding button to existing toolbar

Tags: button, firefox-addon

I have this add-on bar at the button of my firefox window where several buttons from extensions are shown. How can I add my own button there?

Answer (score 0):

you can open the source code of that bar and add your own button

example (I'm on Windows right now):
C:\%AppData%\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\PROFILEID.default\extensions\EXTENSION-TO-EDIT-FOLDER\chrome\content

Comment: I mean when I install my extension the button should be added automatically to this bar.

Comment: I do not "master" XUL and firefox plugins so good for help you... sorry

Comment: This is the code in my ff-overlay.xul file but I cannot see the button anywhere:                                                                          <toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
  <toolbarbutton id="log-toolbar-button" class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional"
    label="&logToolbarButton.label;" tooltiptext="&logToolbarButton.tooltip;"
    oncommand="log.onToolbarButtonCommand()"/>
  </toolbarpalette>

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is with the [Add-on SDK](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk). You can find documentation on adding an Add-on bar button [here](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/sdk/1.0b4/docs/packages/addon-kit/docs/widget.html).
An additional benefit of using the SDK is that your add-ons won't require a restart after they are installed.

Answer (score 0):

hey it is called a status bar    and u should consider putting a statusbar xul element
e.g

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<overlay id="sample"
xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
<statusbar id="status-bar">
<statusbarpanel id="my-panel" label="Hello, World"  />
</statusbar>
</overlay>
```

For more details check this link [statusbar attributes, methods and properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/statusbarpanel)